# Migration from Angular 1.3 to 1.5

Tags: angularjs

I am getting the error that says

```
angular.js:13236 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/ng/areq?p0=fn&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined
at http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:68:12
at assertArg (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1825:11)
at assertArgFn (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1835:3)
at Promise.promise.error    (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10979:11)
at Object.getUserChannels (http://localhost:3000/scripts/services/media-service.js:38:37)
at activate (http://localhost:3000/scripts/controllers/player-controller.js:63:22)
at new <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/scripts/controllers/player-controller.js:28:9)
```

The controller and factory worked before the migration, I cant find any documentation that shows any changes to factories. To me it looks like the controller cannot find the function is the mediaSVC file

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: I think you should first go through this [migration guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration)

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if you used lazy loading of your services and factories in 1.3? If so, please make sure they're loaded in advance before you start calling them when you migrated to 1.5. This was one of the things I've experienced when migrated the large enterprise app from 1.4 to 1.5:

http://www.diatomenterprises.com/migration-history-from-angularjs-1-3-to-1-5-and-then-2-0/

The lazy loading may require a bit of attention and another small library to let it work correctly in 1.5. I can assist you if the problem still exists.